# Javascript setInterval not working in IE7 and IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I am using the Javascript setInterval to keep polling the server for any updates and refresh the screen with the response from the server. I need to support >IE7, and other major browsers.

The setInterval function is getting fired in all the browsers except IE7 and IE8.

According to the suggestions I saw in other posts I have tried setting cache:false on the ajax requests as well as wrapping the setInterval call in an anonymous function. But none of the suggestions seem to work.

Following is the code I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(pollForServerUpdates, 30000);
});


function pollForServerUpdates() {

$.ajax({ url: $.url("Home/GetUpdates"),
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            updateTabelWithCurrentStatus(result);
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });    
}
```

I am not sure if I am missing anything here. Any help is very much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: If the `setInterval` ain't firing, setting the `cache` won't help you.

Comment: It's generally recommended to avoid `setInterval` and use a self-firing `setTimeout` instead. There are issues with `setInterval` where if it is blocked, the interval calls can get queued up and it's possible to have a bunch of them fire all at once. See http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#other.timeouts for more info.

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the console?

Comment: `setInterval` seems to work fine in IE7 (well, tested in IE9 using IE7 browser and document mode): http://jsfiddle.net/mD39Q/1/ The fiddle uses your basic code structure, except instead of the ajax call simply write a message to the console every 2 seconds. I don't think you issue is with the `setInterval` function itself but more related to the consequence of the usage in combination with the ajax call.

Comment: @Pointy. Thanks for that tip. The console is showning an error.  I am seeing error SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number. This is occuring when I am trying to create an element with an  attribute class. Following is the method I am using         function createErrorLink(loadId, step, errorMsg) {
    $('<a />', {
        id: step + loadId,
        onclick: 'return false;',
        title: errorMsg,
        class: 'action download-error',
        loadid: loadId,
        style: 'margin-bottom: -12px;'
    }).appendTo($("#" + step + loadId).parent().empty());
}

Comment: Thanks for all your help. The issue was happening because "class" seems to be a reserved keyword in IE and causing an error. When creating the element, I wrapped the class keyword in quotes and all is well. Thanks Pointy for asking me to look at the console. @Spudley, thanks for the tip, I will be refactoring my code with your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am putting my comments above as the answer to this question. The issue was happening because "class" seems to be a reserved keyword in IE and causing an error. When creating the element, I wrapped the class keyword in quotes and all is well. Thanks Pointy for asking me to look at the console. @Spudley, thanks for the tip, I will be refactoring my code with your suggestion.

Comment: Been there before, just wrapping "class" in double quotes seems to work.